# Rspec 3 view spec undefined method for custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a custom form builder method in a helper module.

```
module MediaHelper
  class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    ... 
  end

 def custom_form_for(data, *args, &proc)
  options = args.extract_options!
  form_for(data, *(args << options.merge(builder:
  MediaHelper::CustomFormBuilder)), &proc)
 end
end
```

This works in the view with `<= custom_form_for(media) do |f| %>`

However it breaks the view spec in RSpec 3, and I receive the error message

`ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method custom_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x007fea32454ce0>:0x007fea34064f98>`

on render

Is it possible to include the helper?

Comment: How exactly you're seeing this error? when you run specs?

Comment: Yes when the spec is run, it renders the view and this error is received.

Answer (score 3):

A custom helper can be included in a view spec with `helper(<module>)`

In the view spec in my case:

```
RSpec.describe 'media_items/new', type: :view do
    helper(MediaHelper)
end
```

When `render` is called in the spec, it correctly renders the view with `<= custom_form_for(media) do |f| %>`